# not declared in this scope c++

Tags: c++, declaration, reachability

I am in the middle of a c++ project and I get the well-known error "not declared in this scope". Specifically "vexp was not declared in this scope". As you can see below, vexp is a vector declared in class Exploration and although I have included Exploration.h in main, vexp is not reachable. On the other hand Exploration::vexp is not acceptable because vexp is not static. **Is making vexp static the only way to access it from main???**

```
#include "exploration.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{

    std::srand (time(NULL));

    for(int i=1; i<9; i++)
    {
        Exploration temp (0,3,3);
        vexp.push_back(temp);
    }
    for(int j=0; j<(int)Exploration::vexp.size(); j++)
    {
        std::cout << Exploration::vexp[j].Vertical;
        std::cout << Exploration::vexp[j].Horizontal;
        std::cout << Exploration::vexp[j].r;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the header:

```
#ifndef EXPLORATION_H
#define EXPLORATION_H
#include<vehicle.h>
#include <vector>

class Exploration : public vehicle
{
    public:
    std::vector <Exploration> vexp;
    Exploration(bool,float,int);
    int r;
    void DangerCheck();
    bool expaxis(int k);
};
#endif // EXPLORATION_H
```

Comment: Once you indent the code properly you see that you forgot to close the brace on the main function.

Comment: Why are you accessing `vexp` as if it was a static member in the second for-loop?

Comment: Apart from that the class design just seems weird. Only public members? Having public members populated in main? That's no encapsulation at all. Once you fix that, you probably don't even need an answer for this question anymore.

Comment: Please explain what this code should do, cause i can´t see any purpose at the moment and your class code is just weird...

Comment: @RedX I edited that, you were too quick :P

Comment: That's the strangest class design I've seen in a while...

Comment: @Ancurio I say that this is not acceptable, since it is not static, I was just testing.

Comment: How can I access the vexp vector in main?? This is the question, please disregard the class design, it will not be all public in the future..

Comment: @Sean everything is public now, it won't stay like that.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to post a weird design, asking why it doesn't work (it's a design flaw), and disregarding every answer that fixes your design.

Comment: @JorenHeit It is my fault if you don't understand the meaning of the question. Apart from that, having everything public in exploration class has nothing to do with my question. Thanks for posting though!!

Comment: @alex777 It wasn't about it being public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vexp` is a non-static member of `Exploration`. Each `Exploration` object you create will have its own `vexp` member. So to access a `vexp`, you need to have an `Exploration` object. That is, the following would work:

```
Exploration exp1(false, 3.0f, 5);
Exploration exp2(true,  6.0f, 10);
exp1.vexp.push_back(exp2);
```

Note that I'm accessing the `vexp` member of `exp1` with `exp1.vexp`. That is the vector that belongs to that particular `Exploration` object. To that vector I am pushing `exp2`.

What exactly you need to do depends on what you're trying to do, and that I am not sure of. It seems that you don't fully grasp object-oriented principles. It should be clear to you that because `vexp` is a non-static member of `Exploration`, it doesn't exist until you create an `Exploration` object. That is, *each* `Exploration` object owns a container of more `Exploration` objects.

It looks as though maybe you just want a `std::vector<Exploration>` that is not a member of `Exploration`. So you just want a container of `Exploration`s, not owned by other `Exploration`s. For that, you would just do:

```
int main()
{
  std::srand (time(NULL));
  std::vector<Exploration> vexp; // vexp has been moved here

  for(int i=1; i<9; i++)
  {
      Exploration temp (0,3,3);
      vexp.push_back(temp);
  }
  for(int j=0; j < vexp.size(); j++)
  {
      std::cout << vexp[j].Vertical;
      std::cout << vexp[j].Horizontal;
      std::cout << vexp[j].r;
      std::cout << '\n';
  }
}
```

Note that `vexp` is now declared local to the `main` function and should be removed from the `Exploration` class.

Comment: @alex777 See my code sample. I think this is what you actually want. `vexp` should not be a member of `Exploration`.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. WHat I want to do, is create objects in a for-loop and push them into a vector. Indeed I haven't grasped well the "static member" part of c++ yet.

Comment: Isn't there a way, to reach vector in main, without being declared there??

Comment: @alex777 You can't use anything that's not declared... That's what header-files are for.

Comment: @JorenHeit I will just make it static and the problem is fixed. I jave included exploration.h but it is not enough.

Comment: @alex777 You could also make it a global variable, outside of both `main` and `Exploration`. However, static/global variables are usually a bad idea. That's something you'll learn as you continue though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to access `vexp` as member of `Exploration` object if you don't want to make it static ex.

```
temp.vexp.push_back(something);
```

But it doesn't seem like you want that. In your case it seems like you should make it static or a global variable.

Comment: indeed I don't want that, because vexp is a vector of type exploration, therefore it contains the objects of the class exploration.

Answer (score 0):

`vexp` is member variable of class `Exploration` so it should be used with instance of class `Exploration`

```
temp.vexp.push_back(SomeVariable);
```

But, it is not recomended to declare your member variable as `public` and use it like this outside class.

Comment: I don't want that, because vexp contains the objects of the class exploration

Comment: thanks, this is what I did before this post, but I didn't like it as a design, so I tried to put each vector in the specific class.

Answer (score 0):

Take the `vexp` out of the class:

```
 std::vector<Exploration> vexp;
```

and:

```
 for(int j=0; j<vexp.size(); j++)
 {
     std::cout << vexp[j].Vertical;
     std::cout << vexp[j].Horizontal;
     std::cout << vexp[j].r;
     std::cout << '\n';
 }
```

Comment: this is how it used to be.. I don't like it as a design.

Comment: Why do you want a different design?

Comment: Because if the vectors are declared in main, then I can't access them in class methods

Comment: Why do you need to access them in class methods?

Answer (score 0):

Is `vexp` meant to be a list of all your `Exploration`s? If so you need to declare it *outside* of the `Exploration` class. You can then do your

```
Exploration temp (0,3,3);
vexp.push_back(temp);
```

and it should work fine.

If on the other hand it's meant to be a vector attached to a specific `Exploration`, then this section is very confusing:

```
  Exploration temp (0,3,3);
  vexp.push_back(temp);
```

You would need instead something like

```
  Exploration myExpl;
  for(int i=1; i<9; i++)
  {
      Exploration temp (0,3,3);
      myExpl.vexp.push_back(temp);
  }
```